# passing request params in twitter call back url

Tags: twitter, callback, twitter-oauth, http-request-parameters

I am working on a CustomerEngagement solution that is integrated with twitter. Looking for suggestion with implementation.

I have configured multiple twitter-apps with a call back URL for each twitter-app (same callback URL), pointing to the same end point in CustomerEngagement application.
I have 2 java methods written, 1 for responding to CRC challenge by twitter(authentication) and 1 for actually receiving the tweet from twitter.

I would like to configure multiple twitter-apps to be served/used by the same single instance of the CustomerEngagement-application from the same endpoint
However, the CustomerEngagement application should have a hint about which twitter-app is responsible for posting the tweet to the application, so that CRC response to twitter can be generated accordingly.

Can I pass a different request parameter in each call back URL of different twitter-apps to identify the app?

I already see a conversation on the same 
https://twittercommunity.com/t/callback-url-with-fixed-query-string-parameters/107821
however, can some one please elaborate on how to achieve this ? I am assuming that this a 2 step process where registering the call back URL ( along with request parameter ) happens to be step 1, followed by setp 2 in which the call back by twitter having the request parameter registered in step 1 is passed !

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Just to clarify here, the CRC functionality is only required by the Account Activity API webhook. What is the purpose of your callback URL - is it to act as a webhook, or is it to perform the server-side piece of the Sign in With Twitter flow?

Comment: The purpose of the callback URL - is it to act as a webhook. We wanted to implement a single REST end point for listening to multiple call back URLs ( each call back URL is distinguished by the value of a particular parameter  passed to the common REST end point ) and respond to the CRC from twitter employing respective consumer_secret. I now figured out that the distinguishing parameter can in-fact be passed as part of call back URL itself (as path param) rather than a separate request parameter. Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 0):

Say your configured `callback_url` is `xyz.com/social/` 
append the query strings params when parsing the callback_url

 tweepy

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, 'xyz.com/social/?var=val') 
url = auth.get_authorization_url()
```

You get an authorization URL that redirects to a twitter login page. After login, it returns

`xyz.com/social/?var=val&oauth_token=****$oauth_verifier=***`